# Visual Basic 2010 Combo Box to datagrid

Tags: vb.net

I am still having issues with the combo box. I have the correct query. I have four tables in MS Access. I need to create a form in Visual Basic that has a combo box and a datagrid. The selection from the combo box will display all relevant information about that person on the datagrid.

For example, if I select John Doe (from the combo box) the datagrid should display:

customer_name (John Doe) order_date (01/01/01) item (Widget) price (9.99)

My query is:

```
`SELECT customers.customer_name, customers.customer_id, orders.order_date, 
orders.order_id, items.item_description, items.item_id, items.item_price
FROM (customers, orders, items) 
LEFT JOIN order_items ON orders.order_id = order_items.order_id
AND items.item_id = order_items.item_id
HERE customers.customer_name = 'John Doe'
`AND customers.customer_id = orders.order_id
ORDER BY orders.order_id, items.item_id;`
```

How do I add John Doe to the combo box and link this query to it, when upon being selected, it displays the result in the datagrid?

Thank you. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try first loading your customers into the combobox, create the event that fires when the user select a value, and then get data for that customer and bind it to the datagridview

```
 Private Sub LoadCustomers()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT customers.customer_name, customers.customer_id FROM customers "
        cmd.Connection = yourConnectionObject

        Dim myCombo As ComboBox

        Dim ds As DataSet
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter

        Try
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(ds, "Customers")

            ' this will load customers to combobox
            With myCombo
                .DataSource = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
                .DisplayMember = "customer_name"
                .ValueMember = "customer_id"
            End With

        Catch ex As Exception
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub

    ' create one event that fires when the user changes the selected value on the combobox
    ' this is only a example, create your own method properly
    Private Sub combobox_selectedvaluechanged() Handles combobox.SelectedValueChanged()
        Dim CustomerId As Integer
        Try
            ' here you get the selected customer id
            CustomerId = ComboBox.SelectedValue

            ' Now you can retrieve data for this customer with your sql query
            ' and for better results use the customer id to run the query

            Dim ds As DataSet = GetDataForCustomer(CustomerId) ' as dataset

            ' bind the returned dataset to the datagrid
            yourdatagrid.Datasource = ds

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```